# How to create dynamic php content?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a Website for a restaurant and since everything is stored on a MySQL Database, I need to implement the navigation logic. Everything is organized in "Cards", a card is a image with a title. Here's what I try to do:
[image]

Because I used PHP mainly for the Database logic, I would like to keep using PHP. So, this is what I thought to do for now. I tried to store the navigation logic in this way.

```
$tree = array("Drinks" => array(
    "Alcholic" => array("Beers", "Vodka", "Wines"),
    "Non-Alcholic" => array("Juices", "Something Else...")
  ),
  "Food" => array(
    //...
  )
);
```

What I have been working for the past days is how to go from the $tree array to actually implementing the logic. I have stored all the item data on the Database already. Thanks in advance!

Comment: that's incorrect. try to save parent-child based navigation in db (using parent_id concept)

Comment: @AlivetoDie I am not familiar with this concept but I'm going right now and look into it. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I wouldn't say it's incorrect @AlivetoDie, it's just a different approach. OP, you'll need to create some routing code, which takes the URL path, e.g, `/alcoholic/wines` and builds the page based on that.

Comment: @Matt so I would need to manually create the folders and the html files?

Comment: @JasperHoward no, you use php to decode the URL path and serve the content accordingly. There are different ways to pass parameters in HTTP, one is with explicit parameters like site.com?a=one&b=two, another is with mod_rewrite like site.com/one/two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, if you are not building the next Amazon, use WordPress + WooCommerce, Shopify, or any other webshop platform. If you want to build from scratch, use Laravel for the basics. It will save you a lot of time and offer way more features that you will ever be able to build yourself.

To answer your question, you need to create a URL scheme to detect what your user is looking at. For example:

```
// to show alcoholic drinks
yoursite.com?type=alcoholic

// to show wines
yoursite.com?category=wines

//to show specific drink
yoursite.com?drink=fancy_wine_from_france
```

then use _GET[] array to determine what variables were passed and what content to show. E.g.

```
if (isset($_GET['drink']))
{
   $drink = $_GET['drink'];
   // select * from your_table where drink = '$drink'
}
if ((isset($_GET['cat']))
{
    $category = $_GET['cat'];
    // select * from your_table where drink_category = '$category' 
}
```

The code is to demonstrate the principle, do not use it in the production

Comment: This is what i was looking for, thanks for suggesting Laravel. I'm going to look more into it and try to implement your example. Thanks a lot!